# How Can I Copy My Macro To The Production Version Of My Workbook?

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have an Excel 2010 workbook in my development environment that contains a macro and form that I now want to put into the production version of this workbook. How can I implement my code and form into the production version of the workbook?

Comment: Right-click on the code/form in the VBE explorer and choose Export.  Import the exported files into your production workbook.

Comment: + 1 @TimWilliams. Dave, if you have both files opened at the same time then you can also drag and drop the module/form from 1 VBA project to the another.

Comment: @Tim Williams - Add you comment as an answer and I will accept it. - Thanks for the help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the code/form in the VBE explorer and choose Export. Import the exported files into your production workbook.